# encoding change when i save into xml file

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I get data from My DB, when I show it on browser windows it was correctly encoded, but when i saved into xml file I get data with encoding changed.
for exemple :
on browser I get this text 
`

> Un texte est une série orale ou **écrite** de mots perçus
>   comme constituant un ensemble cohérent, porteur de sens et utilisant
>   les structures propres à une *langue* à là-bas oç ôlala îlolo
>   (conjugaisons, construction et association des phrases…)

on xml file I get : 
`&lt;p&gt;Un texte est une s&eacute;rie orale ou &eacute;crite de &lt;em&gt;mots&lt;/em&gt; per&ccedil;us comme constituant un ensemble coh&eacute;rent, porteur de sens et utilisant les structures propres &agrave; une langue &agrave; l&agrave;-bas o&ccedil; &lt;strong&gt;&ocirc;lala&lt;/strong&gt; &icirc;lolo (conjugaisons, construction et association des phrases&hellip;)&lt;/p&gt;&#13;`

I don't know what's the problem !!

Comment: your browser is rendering the file, open in notepad to see the real content and look if this is what you want.. note that in xml  char < or > is not allowed and there for stored as &lt; or &gt;

Comment: so is there any problem at all

Comment: when i open the xml file on using notepad++ I see the file encoding UTF-8 whitout ROM but I get always like this character `&lt;p&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved My problem with encoding this text and  deleting the html tag :

```
$description = strip_tags($value['Description']);
$description = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$description);
$xml->startElement("description");
$xml->writeRaw(htmlspecialchars_decode($description));
$xml->endElement();
```

now I have a xml file completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's an htmlentities convertion , place your html content into cdata tag if you want to keep htmlentities `<![CDATA[ <p>myhtmlcontent</p>]]>`

Comment: that's not working, because my text has many html tag so when I use CDATA it became on comment `<!--[CDATA[<p-->`